# How to add custom appender in log4j2.xml

Tags: java, xml, log4j2, perf4j

I have an application for which I want to use perf4j. In log4j2.xml syntax have been changed, I suppose. Here I coundn't find way to declare class attribute for custom appnder class.
 My current `log4j2.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="perf4j">
  <Appenders>
   <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="/home/sarvesh/Desktop/log/perf4j.log" 
     filePattern="/home/sarvesh/Desktop/log/perf4j-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <Async name="rollingFileAppender">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Async>
    <Async name="consoleAppender">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Async>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="rollingFileAppender"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Now I want to add several more appenders, like

```
<appender name="CoalescingStatistics"
                   class="org.perf4j.log4j.AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender">
            <!--
              The TimeSlice option  means timing logs are aggregated every 10 secs.
            -->
            <param name="TimeSlice"  value="10000"/>
            <appender-ref  ref="fileAppender"/>
            <appender-ref  ref="perf4jJmxAppender"/>
        </appender>
```

How to add this appender in log4j2.xml

Comment: The appender you want to use is not compatible, according to the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html) (no plugin factory, no plugin declaration, etc.), so I guess it cannot work as is.